# Routing external traffic to a backup datacenter

Tags: networking, routing, router

I'm planning a backup data center and want all external hosts to transparently connect to DC2 if DC1 goes down. Assume I have public ip 1.1.1.1 at DC1, and public ip 2.2.2.2 at DC2.

Obviously if external hosts connect directly to 1.1.1.1 they cannot transparently switch over. So I thought of using public ip address 3.3.3.3 for the 'active' DC for external hosts to connect to, and a router somewhere in front of the two DC's which will route 3.3.3.3 to either 1.1.1.1 or 2.2.2.2

Now the hard part. do I have to put a router colocated at an ISP and update routes in that box? (Using DNAT perhaps to change 3.3.3.3 to X.X.X.X)? Do ISP's offer an automated way to update routes in their routers? A better way?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting into some really difficult problems here :)

First question you have to ask yourself is what happens to your data when the primary fails. I'll forget about that for now. Second question is what happens to already-connected TCP streams. "Transparent" would imply that they stay connected, which would almost need you to have active-active datacenters.

If you have the same (and really professional) ISP at both datacenters, you can route IPs to one datacenter or the other using (usually) BGP. This needs full cooperation from your very high-end ISP and usually their management of the front-end router at your data-centers.

One "poor man's" solution is to have short TTLs, NS at both datacenters, and the backup DC NS change to backup IPs when they detect that the primary is down.

Comment: I don't know BGP, but does BGP allow a single IP to float between two locations on its network?  Does the DC have to send some type of notification to the router or will it just detect the IP has moved?

Comment: Yes, with BGP you can tell the Internet to route your IP to specific target. But it is not cheap solution (you need to have your own IPs and build AS) and you need cooperation with both datacenters and their ISPs.

Comment: @Telium: if DC1 goes down, you have (at least) TWO problems: 1) ensuring that IP packets that remote clients send to DC1 are routed (from Internet point of view) to DC2; 2) having some magic, in DC2, so that some hosts "reply" to packets addressed to a DC1 IP even if originally, such IP, was assigned to a DC1 host. BGP (that, BTW, you should learn ASAP) has been designed to solve problem 1) and if both DC1 and DC2 are connected to the same upstream ISP, it's relatively easy to setup. Problem 2) is a totally different story, having nothing to do with routing (and, IMHO, more complex to solve!)

Comment: @OndraSniperFlidr You absolutely do *not* have to have your own IP ranges and your own AS . . . *if* you have the same ISP at both sites. You can use ranges as small as a single IP and a private AS (much as you could have private IPs if you were behind a single NAT firewall). You are correct in saying one would need a sizeable IP range and one's own AS if one wants to have *different* ISPs.

Comment: @DamianoVerzulli Problem 2) is usually solved by having servers have the same IPs in the backup center. You have to make sure that packets only go to DC2 when DC1 is down, and existing connections will be closed, but otherwise it will work.

Comment: Or instead of servers having the same IPs, put the IPs on the loadbalancers.